# sqlite3 and python :sqlite3.OperationalError:

Tags: python, sqlite

> table named excercise

```
CODB_cursor.execute(""" CREATE TABLE excercise (
                    distance INTEGER
                    timeOfRun INTEGER
                    avgHR INTEGER
                    dayOfExcercise timestamp
                    )""")

callOnDB.commit()
```

> function that inserts values to the table named excercise

```
def insert_excercise(exc):
    with callOnDB:
        CODB_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO excercise VALUES(:distance,:timeOfRun,:avgHR,:dayOfExcercise)",
                            {'distance':exc.distance,'timeOfRun':exc.timeOfRun,
                            'avgHR':exc.avgHR,'dayOfExcercise':exc.dayOfExcercise})
```

> > in a different file named excercise there is a class named Excercise with self, distance,
> >     timeOfRun, avgHR, dayOfExcercise.
> >     exc_1 is passed to insert_excercise function

```
exc_1 = Excercise(4, 120, 154, datetime.datetime.now())
insert_excercise(exc_1)
```

i keep on getting :::sqlite3.OperationalError: table excercise has 1 columns but 4 values were supplied:::

i don't know why , i have 4 columns named  (distance, timeOfRun, avgHR, dayOfExcercise)
i have  import sqlite3, import datetime, and from excercise import Excercise (this refers to the other file that has the class excercise)

Answer (score 1):

This is creating *one column*!

```
CREATE TABLE excercise (
                    distance INTEGER
                    timeOfRun INTEGER
                    avgHR INTEGER
                    dayOfExcercise timestamp
                    )
```

Syntax requires a `,` between column definitions eg (`col1 TYPE, col2 TYPE, col3 TYPE....`)